# IIS7 appcmd list sites: is there a wildcard to filter on (for i.e. all bindings on port 443)?

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, appcmd

In IIS7, is it possible to filter the results of the appcmd list sites command to, for example, all sites running on port 443?

For example:

```
/appcmd list sites /bindings:http://216.123.123.123:443:*wildcard
```

As it is, I can only filter on the exact binding such as:

```
/appcmd list sites /bindings:http://216.123.123.123:443:some.hostheader.com
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in AppCmd but why not pipe it into FINDSTR, for example:

appcmd list sites | findstr /spin hostheader.com

or 
appcmd list sites | findstr /spin 216.123.123.123:443

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: One caveat is that for the IP you need to "appcmd list sites | findstr 216.123.123.123".

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this with AppCmd:
`%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe list site /bindings:http/*:8315:`

Comment: this checks for strict equality though and will not display `http/*:80:,net.tcp/808:*` for example